# How to show decimal numbers in d3 radialProgress?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im using the d3 component  [radialProgress.js](http://www.brightpointinc.com/download/radial-progress-source-code/)

But its not possible to show decimal numbers, for example:

1.37% it only shows 1%.

Is there some configuration that i can change it?

Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

I found this function:

```
function labelTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(_currentValue, a);
    _currentValue = i(0);

    return function(t) {
        _currentValue = i(t);
        this.textContent = Math.round(i(t)) + "%";
    }
}
```

Wich is used by:

```
 label.transition().duration(_duration)
                .tween("text",labelTween);
```

The **a** parameter in the **labelTween** function is the value that will be on the label text. But this value is already rounded when the **labelTween** function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not configurable, the value is rounded in the code. You need to replace

```
.text(function (d) { return Math.round((_value-_minValue)/(_maxValue-_minValue)*100) + "%" })
```

with

```
.text(function (d) { return (_value-_minValue)/(_maxValue-_minValue)*100 + "%" })
```

to disable the rounding. There are a few other places where this needs to happen as well:

```
label.datum(Math.round(ratio*100));
```

should be

```
label.datum(ratio*100);
```

and

```
this.textContent = Math.round(i(t)) + "%";
```

should be

```
this.textContent = i(t) + "%";
```

Comment: Actually this is not sufficient.